# Third argument {sub} of substitute() when :echo

Tags: vim

Whether the third argument {sub} is a string or an expression result in different behaviours that I can't understand:

```
:echo substitute(" ", " ", "ab\nc", "")
ab
c

:echo substitute(" ", " ", '\="ab\nc"', "")
cb
```

It seems that in the first case, `\n` splits line in two at the point, while in the second case, `\n` moves the cursor to the beginning of the same line. How to explain this?

Comment: Which version of Vim do you have? I get two identical outputs, (`ab<cr>c`, the same as your first example); I'm usingVim 7.4-1-884

Comment: And what is the output with `'\="ab\nc\n"'` ?

Comment: @yolenoyer Vim 7.3, without patches information. the output of `'\="ab\nc\n"'` is `cb`. I switch to Vim 7.4-1-963, then I get two identical outputs, the same as the first example. Why?

Comment: @yolenoyer I noticed you use `<CR>` to represent a line break. Shouldn't it be `<NL>`? As I know, `<CR>` means carriage return and `<NL>` means new line.

Comment: you're right with <cr>/<nl>

Answer (score 0):

> I switch to Vim 7.4-1-963, then I get two identical outputs, the same
>   as the first example. Why?

[`Patch 7.3.225`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/oZ69twv8eLM/7uBiiSCI6sgJ)

```
Problem:    Using "\n" in a substitute inside ":s" does not result in a line break.
Solution:   Change behavior inside vim_regexec_nl().   Add tests.  (Motoya Kurotsu)
Files:      src/regexp.c, src/testdir/test79.in, src/testdir/test79.ok,
            src/testdir/test80.in, src/testdir/test80.ok,
            src/testdir/Makefile, src/testdir/Make_amiga.mak,
            src/testdir/Make_dos.mak, src/testdir/Make_ming.mak,
            src/testdir/Make_os2.mak, src/testdir/Make_vms.mms
```